# Spock test for Mono.flatmap

Tags: spring-boot, mono, spock

How to spock test this function of Class AService, thanks?

@Service

```
Class AService(val service: Service) 
{

  fun toTestMethod(a: A, bMono: Mono<B>): C {
    val currentMap: Mono<List<Map<*,*>>> = bMono.flatMap {b->
        service.method(ApiResource.GOOD, b)}

    return C(currentMap, a)
  }
}
```

I tried something like below, but 0 invocations of the function
 service.method(ApiResource.GOOD, b)

```
    def bMono = Mono.just(new B())
    when:
    def serviceResponse = aService.toTestMethod(a, bMono)

    then:
    1 * service.method(_ as Service,_ as B)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show how `aService` is instantiated and where `service` comes from. And please learn why an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is important to answer a question, not just snippets without context. Ask yourself as a software developer: If you only had the provided code from someone else, could you answer the question in any meaningful way like this?

Comment: Solved.dont forget to use .subscribe() in when block after the function to be test.

Comment: Then please delete the question if it was just a mistake unrelated to Spock. An unclear, unanswered question will help nobody here and just pollute the SO platform.